# Will older 802.11a/b/g device affect 802.11ac wave 2?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11ac

Given the silly number of antennas on the newer 802.11ac wave 2 devices, will older 802.11a/b/g devices still slow down the network?  [Based on this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/02/wifi-basics-part-3-802-11ac/), I'm really wondering about that.

There are a ton of antennas on those newer devices. The wireless router shown in the article claims to have 5330Mbps tri-band throughput.

Comment: Well, 11b definitely won't, because it's not using the 5 GHz band.

Comment: @Maelish 802.11n devices will slow down 802.11ac networks.  802.11 A/B devices will slow down 802.11n networks also.

Answer (score 0):

Older generation devices working in the same band will always have a small effect on newer generation devices. Newer generation devices have to enable protection methods to keep the older devices from stepping on their transmissions, and those protection mechanisms have a small performance hit. Also, a slower devices use more airtime to send the same amount of data compared to a faster device. So if your slower devices actually need to transfer a lot of data, they contend with the fast devices for the airtime.

Nothing about 802.11ac or even so-called "wave 2" changes this reality.